# How do I create a master list in excel that displays the most recent entry from each tab on a worksheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel, tabs, master

I'm creating a workspace (on excel 2003) with three worksheets: active, inactive, and master-list. Tabs will move between active and inactive, based on whether or not I'm currently focused on them. I want the master-list to display the most recent entry from every tab that is currently on the active sheet.

Every tab on active/inactive looks the same (has the same columns and rows). I just want to aggregate all of my active data and still maintain the ability to move pages between active and inactive worksheets. I'm sure it can be done, but it's beyond my working knowledge of excel...

And help is much, much appreciated!

Comment: I'm confused - what are these "tabs" that you have on each sheet? What are the "pages" you're referring to? Can you post a screenshot?